# Converting Java ordinary for loop which have return statement to Java8 IntStream

Tags: java, java-8

Below is my ordinary for loop and I want to refactor the same code to use java8 IntStream.

```
for(int i=0; i<= historyList.size(); i++) {
            if (isExist(historyList, status, i)) {
                return historyList.get(i).getCreated();
            }
        }
```

And below is the refactored `IntStream` version

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, historyList.size()).forEach(i -> {
            if (isExist(historyList, status, i)) {
                return historyList.get(i).getCreated(); -- Error: Unexpected return value
            }
        });
```

But getting error at the return as shown above.

> Error: Unexpected return value

How to refactor the above code in a proper way?

Comment: Your question is missing a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve which would be helpful.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  I feel that the original version of your code is more readable than any "streamed" version you could write.

Answer (score 5):

[`IntStream#forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#forEach-java.util.function.IntConsumer-) returns nothing (`void`), so you cannot return any data from within it.  Instead, you can `map` the data to the type you wish to return, and then return it (or some other value):

```
return IntStream.rangeClosed(0, historyList.size())
                .filter(i -> isExist(historyList, status, i))
                .map(historyList::get)
                .map(History::getCreated) // Or whatever the object is called.
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null); // Or some other value.
```

Comment: Worth noting that depending on what to `isExist` method does, it might be better to rewrite it to take the current `History` rather than (presumably) accessing the `List` by index. That would save a lot of random access to the `List`.